# Connection string to connect to a database on a virtual server on a different PC

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

I would like to connect to a PC, where's a server as a virtual machine is running on it.

I will do that with an ASP.NET connection string. That's how I was using it when I had an local database. How do I have to put it to connect to the virtual machine's database?

```
<add 
    name="data_SQL" 
    connectionString="Data Source=LOCALHOST\;Initial Catalog=crm;Integrated Security=True" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "Localhost" use the machine name (and the instance name if you have some).

For example:

```
<add name="data_SQL" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER\INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=crm;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: So I don't think I really know, what you mean with instance, but is it enough if I type in Data Source=SERVER\?